# Using formal definition of a limit to prove (-1/2)^n converges to L = 0

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Hey there I'm trying to solve a convergence question that uses the formal definition of convergence to show that (-1/2)^n converges to L = 0.

I have gotten up to the below stages but I am unsure if it is correct and I can't seem to find the correct solution that explains steps:

|(-1/2)^n| < epsilon
-> |(-1)^n/2^n| < epsilon
-> 1/2^n < epsilon
-> 2^n > 1/epsilon
From here I do not know how to isolate "n" so I can prove that N is the least integer above what my epsilon value will equal, thus proving that the sequence is convergent with limit L = 0

Comment: Take logarithm.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I tried to do this but ended up with a really gross difficult epsilon side where it was n = log(1/epsilon)/log(2) which I'm not sure still follows the formal definition

Comment: I agree with the previous comment about taking logarithms.  However, there is another approach that you might not realize is valid.  For any **fixed** $\epsilon > 0, ~(1/\epsilon)$ is a fixed finite number.  As $n \to +\infty, ~2^n > n$ must also $\to +\infty.$  Therefore, there must exist an $N \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ such that $2^N > (1/\epsilon).$  Further, having proven the existence of $N$, you have that for any $n \in \Bbb{R}, ~n > N \implies 2^n > 2^N > (1/\epsilon).$